Ideal 3 Phase Rectifier
I am working on a 3 phase PFC and implementing third harmonic injection. In order to do so, I use the min-max method. This would be trivial in an MCU, but everything is being done in analog. I have been using the circuit below so far. The input signals, ABC, are representations of the incoming AC and range from 0-3.3V centered around 1.65V. The node "OUT" should represent (max(A,B,C)+min(A,B,C))/2 and goes directly to the input of a buffer.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I believe the issue is how high the Vf of the diodes are. With my small signal amplitude, the 500-600mV drop of the diodes cuts away the majority of my signal. When switching to Schottky diodes, the leakage current through the bottom diodes when they are reverse biased throws off the measurement significantly as well.
For a single phase, you can overcome the diode drop with a precision rectifier/ideal rectifier circuit. Is there something similar for 3 phases that I could use? The current solution uses two op-amps (buffer and scale+offset). This could be an XY problem so I am open to other solutions to get that same third harmonic triangle.

It's not clear what you are trying to do - PFC but at 3.3V? Also, R3 and R4 seem dubious. Regardless, you can use an op-amp precision rectifier circuit to treat the non-ideal voltage drop - both in simulation and on the breadboard.

This is but one circuit within the PFC. Look into SVPWM. Third Harmonic Injection moves the phantom neutral of the PFC up and down at 180Hz to avoid the AC line "kissing" the DC link. It allows you to run a much lower DC bus voltage. In my case I can take my 880V output down to ~810. R3 and R4 are to give some kind of impedance to ground besides parasitics so the nodes aren't too sensitive. I see your point though, I can try removing them.

You cannot use the conventional 3 phase rectifier if you need to PFC. You can only PFC on individual phases and then bring together at a DC point.

What is the source impedance of A, B and C?

A simple solution (supposing you have some supplies available) : simply use 6 "ideal diodes" made of an opamp and a diode, and otherwise keep your current schematics
If you need some more explanations about ideal diodes (or if you want a high speed version), then you can look at this old post : How can an op-amp act as a precision diode?.
NB : there might be simpler/cheaper solutions, but this one sticks quite closely to what you already have

I had considered that, but was hoping for a solution using less than the 7 or so op-amps I would need. The board has +/- 5 and 3.3V available.
